# Need to authenicate my Spring MVC web Application by Active Directory LDAP and then to the database together

Tags: spring, authentication, active-directory, spring-ldap

My requirement is authenticate the login request to the Active Directory LDAP and to the local db as the user may be created manually or by the LDAP. 
I am loading all the users i my database in a users table but i want to make the dynamic login to LDAP for the ldap users if user did not get authenticated by LDAP with invalid login or invalid user then only i need to authenticate it to the db.

Answer (score 0):

Am not certain on this, so obviously please confirm, but in your Spring [security.xml](https://github.com/gmazza/tightblog/blob/24e5eb37268d3880b2be7671becf671e0765b32b/app/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/security.xml#L70), set up two authentication providers under your authentication manager, first your ldap one and then your database one.  A failure with the LDAP authentication should cause the DB one to activate and give the user a second chance to authenticate with the same credentials. Also see [this article](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/ROLLER/Roller+5.1+with+LDAP) for some testing I had done earlier with Active Directory and Spring Security.